# Change a javascript variable and save it to the file

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am reading an array object from a javascript file and then adding an object to it when the user clicks a button. However, when I refresh the page or close the browser and open the file again, the array object remains unchanged, that is the item added by the user doesn't reflect in the array object.

Is there any way of updating a javascript variable such that it is updated in the javascript file as well?

Comment: No, there is not. Mostly because usually the source script file is totally out of your reach. Have a look at `localstorage` or a serverside database instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use local storage. Here's a useful object for using localstorage:

```
var LocalStorageManager = {
    setValue: function(key, value) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    getValue: function(key) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
};
```

You would store the data like this:

```
LocalStorageManager.setValue("key", data);
```

And retrieve that data like this:

```
var data = LocalStorageManager.getValue("key");
```

Without localstorage:

```
function writeToFile(filename, string){
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fh = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, false, 0);
    fh.WriteLine(string);
    fh.Close();
 }

function readFile(filename){
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fh = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1, false, 0);
    var lines = "";
    while (!fh.AtEndOfStream) {
        lines += fh.ReadLine() + "\r";
    }
    fh.Close();
    return lines;
}
```

This would be the easiest way, in javascript to accomplish this. In NodeJS:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Comment: however, won't the localstorage be erased once i close the computer and/or the browser?

Comment: It won't be removed until someone clears the browser cache.

Comment: It's good for passing data along. But, not good for storing data for very long periods of time.

Comment: so apart from server-side scripting, there's no way can I store data for long periods of time?

Comment: Correct. Other than that, there's not really a way unless you are using NodeJS, which can do this easily. I've included an example of how easy it is in node just fyi. How long are you looking to store the data?